# How to capture the exception of async methods in constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms program, the following is the constructor, which creates a timer to throttle the expensive async call.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            _flag = false;
            _timer.Stop();
            try
            {
                Task.Run(async () => await Presenter.Search()); // Call async DB calls
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // Cannot capture the Exception of `Presenter.Search()`
            {
                MessageLabel.Text = "Error:....";
            }
        };
    }

    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private bool _flag;
```

And the click event trigger the async call

```
public void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_flag)
    {
        _flag = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Howe to capture the exception of `Presenter.Search()` and show the error in the form?

Will it block the UI thread if I change

```
Task.Run(async () => await Presenter.Search());
```

to

```
Presenter.Search().RunSynchronously()
```

?

Comment: You can make the tick handler async and `await` that `Task.Run`, or `try/catch` `Presenter.Search` and invoke `MessageLabel` Also, it doesn't look like the `Task.Run` is needed unless search is blocking something.

Comment: Will it block the UI thread if I change `Task.Run(async () => await Presenter.Search())` to `Presenter.Search().Wait()`?

Comment: @JSteward  He's using Task.Run because he can't await Presenter.Search in his version of the constructor (C# allows that now).  He should be calling PresenterSearch directly however he can't capture the aggregated exception easily doing that.  I recommend a new async void method but I know that get's discouraged.  I'm going to make a fix for this and present it unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII `Presenter.Search` isn't in the constructor it's the event handler for the timer

Comment: @JSteward You're correct!  I wasn't paying attention :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle exceptions form `Presenter.Search` just use an async event handler for your `Tick` event.

```
_timer.Tick += async (s, e) =>
{
    _flag = false;
    _timer.Stop();
    try
    {
        await Presenter.Search(); // Call async DB calls
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Cannot capture the Exception of `Presenter.Search()`
    {
        MessageLabel.Text = "Error:....";
    }
};
```

Comment: Interesting, I updated the code as your answer. However, the UI is sort of freeze when the function `Presenter.Search()` is running.

Comment: If `Presenter.Search` is freezing the UI then it's not fully async, some part of it blocking. In that case you can use `Task.Run` to offload synchronous work to another thread. So that line of code becomes `await Task.Run(() => Presenter.Search)`. Note that you await the Task.Run which will allow you to capture exceptions thrown by `Search` and that you don't need an async lambda since `Search` already returns a `Task`

Comment: What's different when using `await Task.Run(async () => await Presenter.Search())` in the new solution?